# /etc/network/interfaces versus addresses set via ip addr add

Tags: networking

I'm having a difficulty understanding which settings my Ubuntu system is going to use.

When  I'm modifying ip address settings via `ip addr add` or `ip addr del` these seem to be reflected immediately on the interface, if I check via `ifconfig` or just `ip addr`. However, changes are not reflected in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu. Can anybody help me understand the link between what I do with the `ip` command suite and the configuration file, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ip addr add` is, as you've seen, for temporary changes. Persistent settings may be edited into `/etc/network/interfaces`. Use any text editor such as gedit, nano, kate or vim and edit the file. I suggest something like the following:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

Of course, select an address outside the DHCP pool used in the router and substitute your details here.

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0
```

And test:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: So whatever I set via ifconfig or ip addr gets lost on next boot unless I manually modify /etc/network/interfaces, correct?

Comment: Yes, just exactly.

Comment: And another problem bites the dust and gets upvoted!  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First, neither tool you are using writes to `/etc/network/interfaces` , they manage the routing table in the kernel directly.

Secondly, NetworkManager overides /etc/network/interfaces , so /etc/network/interaaces is only part of the configuration

For fruther information see:

http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-is-a-routing-table/

From the second link

> Your routing table is created automatically, based on the current TCP/IP configuration of your Linux / UNIX computer. You can manually add / modify / edit routing table using route and ip command.

so the ip command(s) you are using are over riding your configuration, not writing a config file

Comment: I don't think NetworkManager overwrites `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: you may be right, it certainly will over ride the file. It has been a while since I looked at the details

Comment: @saiarcot895: NetworkManager will get precedence over `/etc/network/interfaces` when both are set..

Comment: @heemayl  It may or may not depending on 'managed=no' or 'managed=yes' set in NetworkManager.conf.

Comment: @chili555: Didn't get into that part, so `managed=false` means NetworkManager will be preferred?

Comment: @heemayl `managed=false` means that NM will _not_ manage an interface declared in `/etc/network/interfaces`. That is the default.

Comment: By default, NM will only manage and configure interfaces that are *not* configured in /e/n/interfaces by default. As @chili555 wrote. And routing table is just one part of what you can set with ip(8). And don't use ifconfig(8), route(8) or arp(8), as they are obsoleted and replaced with ip(8), which can do everythin and more than the old ones.